# Is possible write $\gamma \in [2, 0)$ under certain condition?

Tags: order-theory

I am writing an academic paper. I have a variable that vary its value from $2$, when speed is zero, until $0$ at high speed.

So, I would like write that $\gamma \in [2, 0)$ and not $\gamma \in (0, 2]$. Is correct my form?

Comment: No, it is not. By conventions of interval notation $[2, 0)$ is either the empty set or simply not defined. Why not just say what you just said rather than trying to find notation? It will probably be clearer for the reader.

Comment: I'd definitely avoid that $[2,0)$. Any math gourmet would take that notation amiss and prejudge you as an amateur.

Comment: Ok. This is the main question and thaks for the remarks, but now I have a second question, another interval that is function of this one and another unknow parameter and I do not know if this second is ascending or descending, but with $\gamma \in [2, 0)$ I obtain a structure more ordered. But if this is bad, I rewrite the equations.